# Partition table on external HD gone

Tags: partitioning

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04. I have a 2Tb external Western Digital HD that stopped working overnight, and I'm worried I might not be able to recover files from it anymore. It has three partitions, all ext4.

If I check in partitionmanager, the disk is there and the correct size is reported, however, there does not appear to be a partition table.

So I have installed a few tools such as TestDisk, and when I run that and try to analyze the disk, it reports an error for every cylinder read and the actual HD does not appear to do anything.

Is there anything else I could try?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `fixparts` . I have recoverd  corrupted partition table of my hdd using this tool. More info: http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/ and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/fixparts.8.html